# Host not recognizing my USB devices

Tags: usb-host-mode

I bought a Romanian Android tablet, EvoTab3, with Android version 4.0.3 and kernel version 3.0.8+. I want to connect some devices such as a mouse and flash memory to this tablet that will be the host station, using an OTG cable (mini to USB A). I did the following steps:

1. USB debugging is ON
2. Download an app USB host controller that display the info: "S3C USB Host driver not found" " Root hub present, USB Host mode is active!"
3. I followed the steps from the post Android USB host and hidden devices.

I did not get any results, connected devices are not detected. 
Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to request the correct driver from Evolio for your device, i think this is a pure driver issue.

http://evolio.ro/en/tablet-pc/evotab-3-tablet-pc.html